# Wygwam embed media class missing

Tags: wygwam

In V2.7 when you used the embed media toolbar button it automatically wrapped the embed code in a div with a class of embed_media.

In V3.3.3 this no longer happens. The first time I did it it was just wrapped in a P tag, the next time it was a Div, but with no class. This makes applying CSS formatting for responsive sizing impossible.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I've just discovered that V3.3.3 has 18 plugins (in the theme folder) whilst V2.7 had 42. One of those plugins missing is embedmedia, which in turn looks like it needs another, iframedialog. So looks like a deliberate removal of functionality rather than a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the plugin is missing there is a solution to wrap an iframe in a div and give it a class. [See this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16758/wygwam-automatically-wrap-media-embed-with-custom-html)