# Getting CKEditor in Wyvern to not use inline styles

Tags: css, ckeditor, wyvern

I've seen this post:
[Remove inline styles from WYGWAM](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25609/request-disabled-image-size-inline-css?lq=1) -  but it's for WYGWAM. Has anyone successfully changed CKEditor's behavior, from Wyvern, to output this:

```
<img src="blat.gif" height="200" width="200">
```

Instead of this:

```
<img src="blat.gif" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
```

It's not clear which file I should edit.

Comment: You should be able to write some jquery that will do that for you on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Hrmm. I wouldn't recommend changing core files.

:p I feel like being awful today. Here's a PHP solution (turn template on PHP output):

```
<?php
echo preg_replace("/height\=\\"(\d*)\\" width=\"(\d*)\\"/", 'style="height:$1px; width:$2px;"', '{wyvern_image_field}');
?>
```

This regex will turn

```
<img src="blat.gif" height="200" width="200">
```

to

```
<img src="blat.gif" style="height:200px; width:200px;">
```

**bunch of edits** that was some quote nightmare to get right, lol. AND OH, woops, you wanted it to go the **other** way. Hold on, regex coming up in a few minutes!

Here ya go, buddy!

```
<?php
echo preg_replace("/style=\\"height:(\d*)px; width:(\d*)px;\\"/", 'height="$1" width="$2"', '{wyvern_image_field}');
?>
```

This will take this

```
<img src="blat.gif" style="height:200px; width:200px;">
```

and produce this!

```
<img src="blat.gif" height="200" width="200">
```

Answer (score 1):

Wyvern has a similar config file, you can add this line to it:

config.disallowedContent = 'img{width,height}';

Comment: I added to line 38 of /themes/third_party/wyvern/config.js? but the field is not responding.